# I can't make a git commit (E325 Attention)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am not familiar with using git, when I first committed my react app to my github repository
it was completely fine. After some changes I committed second time but it say I need to delete index. lock file, after deleting index. lock file and I tried to commit again, but it say E325 attention. I have no idea how to handle this and can someone explain me how to use git commit wisely, sorry for wasting your times, Thanks[image]

Comment: The complaint is about a vim ".swp" (swap) file, which vim uses to keep track of ongoing editors. Git has started vim for you because Git has been told that you prefer to use vim to edit your commit messages. If you don't actually prefer vim, that's what you need to update. VSCode should probably be running Git differently so that this doesn't happen, but that's a VSCode issue, not a Git issue. (Software is complicated!)

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete this swap file.

`.git` is a hidden directory that you can't see it.You just need to move into `./ReactDevelopment/darnit-replicate/.git/` directory and delete the file named `.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp` and commit again.